# remove keys from pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.dataframe with a column 'ID_number'.
My second dataframe has also a column with 'ID_number'. 
Now I would like to remove all ID_numbers from my first dataframe that are in my second dataframe. Moreover I should mention that the ID_number should be the key. So that the entire row gets removed if the key gets removed.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

keys1 = [1,2,3,4]
keys2 = [3,4,5,6]
data1 = np.reshape(range(20),[4,5])
data2 = np.reshape(range(20,40),[4,5])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,index=keys1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,index=keys2)

df1[-(df1.index.isin(df2.index))]
```